# OOP in PHP, pass variable & output directly with function name

Tags: php, function, class, oop

I am newbie to **OOP**. I created this code and I know how to call it with this way

```
$john = new people('Bla', 'bla');
```

and call it using `$john->boy();`
But i want to call functions directly and pass specific (for boy.. `$name, $beard` for girl... `$name, $hair, $eyes`) variables on it.

```
<?php

    class people {

        public $name;
        protected $hair;
        protected $eyes;
        protected $beard;

        public function __constructor($name, $hair, $eyes, $beard) {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->hair = $hair;
            $this->eyes = $eyes;
            $this->beard = $beard;
        }

        public function getName() {

            return $this->name;
        }

        public function getHair() {

            return $this->hair;
        }

        public function getEyes() {

            return $this-eyes;
        }

        public function getBeard() {

            return $this->beard;
        }

        public static function boy() {

            $name = getName();
            $beard = getBeard();

            echo $name . ' has ' . $beard . ' beard';
        }

        public static function girl() {

            $name = getName();
            $hair = getHair();
            $eyes = getEyes();

            echo $name . ' has ' . $hair . ' hair and ' . $eyes . ' eyes';
        }
    }
```

**And call & output directly with function name:**

```
people::boy('John', 'long');
people::boy('Steve', 'small');
people::girl( 'Eva', 'long', 'blue' );
```

Comment: can't call a non-static method from a static context (by using this->... the class must be instantiated via new)

Comment: What you want does not require classes. You simply need a function with parameters. E.g. `function boy($name, $beard) { // code }`

Comment: `__constructor` btw is invalid in OOP. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php - I honestly don't know where you got that from, but I'd sure like to know.

Comment: As a newbie to OOP i was following some tutorials, just changed some names and replaced some functions XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like ka_lin sad, you can't call a non-static method from a static context; so, what you can do for that code works is this:

```
<?php

class people {
    protected $name;
    protected $hair;
    protected $eyes;
    protected $beard;

    public function __construct($name, $hair, $eyes, $beard) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->hair = $hair;
        $this->eyes = $eyes;
        $this->beard = $beard;
    }

    public function getName() {

        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getHair() {

        return $this->hair;
    }

    public function getEyes() {

        return $this->eyes;
    }

    public function getBeard() {

        return $this->beard;
    }

    public static function boy($name, $beard) {
        $boy   = new self($name, null, null, $beard);
        $name  = $boy->getName();
        $beard = $boy->getBeard();

        echo $name . ' has ' . $beard . ' beard' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function girl($name, $hair, $eyes) {
        $girl = new self($name, $hair, $eyes, null);
        $name = $girl->getName();
        $hair = $girl->getHair();
        $eyes = $girl->getEyes();

        echo $name . ' has ' . $hair . ' hair and ' . $eyes . ' eyes' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

people::boy('John', 'long');
people::boy('Steve', 'small');
people::girl( 'Eva', 'long', 'blue' );
```

Comment: This answer should have contained the fact that `__constructor` is incorrect.